# Why do I no longer see top-voted answers first?

Tags: discussion

I used to just see the best answers first, but in recent months it seems as if the default sort is "active"... I want to see the top-voted answers by default. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think if you just click on the 'Votes' tab at the top of the answer list (to the top right below the comments on the question) it should remember your choice. I'm still seeing them sorted by votes first so I'm not sure this was a system change.